# Windows Command Prompt - For statement & Loops

Tags: batch-file

I have two problems.

First: Not all txt files will open at once. One file will open for viewing then I will close it and then the next in line of the directory will open and so on an so forth until all files have been processed. How do i get all files to open without having to close previous txt file?

Second: The variable count never counts up. It continuously echos 1. How do i get it to count up? I'm trying to get the count to echo out how many txt files where opened within directory.

```
set /A Count=0
for %%I in (*.txt) do set /A Count=%Count%+1
echo %Count%
```

Comment: I suppose if you're `start`ing those `.txt` files instead of `echo`ing them, _because they're normally a file type with a registered application_, then maybe, `Start "" "%%I"`

Comment: I did try the start command, but when it tried to start file the windows 'How do you want to open this file?' would pop up and i would have to select notepad. It does this even though I have notepad as the default txt loader.

Comment: It was my understanding, and that's why I wrote it, that `.txt` files were default set to open automatically in Windows by notepad. Perhaps you need to ensure that the defaults are set again properly or instead use `Start "" notepad "%%I"`.

Answer (score 0):

for %%I in (*.txt) do set /A Count=Count+1&"%%I"

`%count%` is the *parse-time* value of `count` - when the line was parsed, not the *run-time* value (see articles about `delayed expansion` using the `search` facility in the top bar).

The `set /a` syntax allows variables to be named "nude" to access the *run-time* value.

Another method would be

```
set /a count+=1
```

The `open file` facility is missing from your code. `"%%I"` *should* open the file using your default editor.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to finally get it to work with your help. I didn't know delayed expansion existed until today.